# Can we display the second section first???

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Statically I have mentioned the number of sections for the UICollectionView as 3 as shown in the below:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
            return 3;
    }
```

Now I am trying to display the second section when the application launches instead of showing the first section.As UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView. I wrote the code that:

```
[mCollectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 568) animated:YES];
```

but it was displaying the first section only.Is there any other way to display the second section in UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[collectionview scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: could be good to use animated: NO to avoid the user watching the scrollview scroll on the beginning (that may confuse them)

Comment: Hi @kalpesh I have tried the solution which you have given but I am facing an issue that the section header is hiding as it was displaying from cell index position when I scroll to top then it was showing the section header but when the application launches the section header was not shown.

Comment: @usernew i have check actually it depend on your uicollection view cell size and number of item in section . I think